# Queryset on Django

Tags: python, django

I want to retrieve data from 10 data from largest to smallest, I use a queryset like this and it runs smoothly.

```
similarity_scores = Similarity.objects.all().order_by('-similarity_score')[:10]
```

but when i want to fetch data first_movie with word "Innocence (2014)" and sort it from data 10 from largest to smallest, i use queryset just add .filter() like this and get error

```
similarity_scores = Similarity.objects.all().filter(first_movie ="Innocence (2014)").order_by('-similarity_score')[:10]
```

Error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Innocence (2014)'
```

**did I make mistake?** I really appreciate all the answers even if they are explanations, because I've read the docs from Django I can't understand them yet. Thank you

Comment: Show us your models.py please. Is the first_movie field a CharField? You probably have it declared as an IntegerField Or a ForeignKeyField.

Comment: thanks for reminding me about the models that ForeignKeyField, problem solved